# Delay in displaying data on tableView in ios swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, reloaddata

> Hi,
>
> I'm trying to parse data on to the listview and am able to get it and
>   display it on the tableView but the problem is it is taking hell lot
>   of time to display it on the tableview. Please find the my code below.

```
func jsonParsing()
    {
        activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()

        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest (URL: deviceListURL)
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                // If there is an error in the web request, print it to the console
                println(error.localizedDescription)
            }

            var err: NSError?
            if(data != nil) {
                var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as! NSMutableArray

                //println("Data: \(jsonResult)")

                var dataDict: NSDictionary
                for dataDict : AnyObject in jsonResult {
                    var device_id: NSString = dataDict.objectForKey("deviceId") as! NSString
                    var device_name: NSString = dataDict.objectForKey("deviceName") as! NSString
                    var device_status: NSInteger = dataDict.objectForKey("status") as! NSInteger

                    let dictionary = [self.deviceID: device_id, self.deviceName: device_name, self.Status: device_status]
                    self.myObject.addObject(dictionary)
                }

                println("My object = %@", self.myObject)
                println(self.myObject.count)

                if self.myObject.count != 0 {
                    self.reloadTable()

                }
            }

            if err != nil {
                // If there is an error parsing JSON, print it to the console
                println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
            }


        })

        task.resume()

    }
```

Comment: self.reloadTable() is creating the issue it seems!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The completion handler is running in a background queue, not the main thread. UI updates have to happen on the main thread, though.

Try calling `reloadTable()` on the main thread:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    self.reloadTable()
})
```

(I just typed this in here untested, so I hope it works this way)